# How can I create new CustomPostType record using wp.api.collections?

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, wp-api

I would be very grateful for your help. Already racked my brain for today!

So, I used the CPT UI plugin and created my custom post type with it. Immediately when setting it up, **I enabled RestAPI support** *(I always do this)*, and I also used the default *WP_REST_Posts_Controller* setting.

When I give the command to add the default Post

```
var review = new wp.api.models.Post( { title: 'Test post' } );
review.save();
```

everything is fine!

But when I try to specify my registered Review type instead of Post, I get an error
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: wp.api.models.Review is not a constructor**

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, sure, I could disable the plugin and create own CPT by php, but I need special custom fields for he CPT (I'm using ACF Pro plugin); it is not so good idea to do the one half of the job from script and the second using plugin. IMHO...

Comment: How you register the CPT doesn't matter to other plugins, all that matters is that it was registered, ACF Pro isn't double checking if the CPT was registered by the CPT UI plugin. By using CPT UI you've eliminated a large number of sources of help, not to mention that a lot of potential answers would no longer apply to you

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying look wp.api.models under DevTools - really, 'Review' nope; but 'Reviews' are presented. But second trouble: jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2          POST https://dev.praxiscode.dev/index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/reviews 404 (Not Found) - it's caused by the line 'review.save();'. It means (as I see) that my CPT has been created, backbone  is applied - but route is ncorrect. Have I develop custom route for my CPT?

Comment: is there no way to export what you've done in CPT UI for debugging? With `register_post_type` you can edit it into your question and I could see exactly what you did in full and spot any issues

Comment: visiting https://dev.praxiscode.dev/index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/ implies that your REST API route is not `wp/v2/reviews`, it is `wp/v2/Review`, note the capitalisation. I don't know why CPT UI has done this but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. What this means for the `wp.api.models` class though I don't know. Note that you do not need to use `wp.api.models` to work with the REST API, it's a helper library. A lot of people just use `fetch` or `jQuery.get`/`jQuery.ajax`

Comment: Yes, @TomJNowell I rewrite my code using ajax, without axios library and wp.api.models. All are working :) thank you for idea "you do not need" (y)